# Pandas multiple transform-groupby-aggregate at once - speedup

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have to do multiple transform-groupby-aggregate operations and am currently doing those one after the other, but it's very slow:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
import pandas as pd
fsc = ['E', 'P']
mtx = pd.DataFrame({'EQ': {'2': 'P', '9970': 'P', '9971': 'P'},
'HOURS': {'2': 7.2000000000000002, '9970': 18.0, '9971': 10.0},
'LOC': {'2': 'A', '9970': 'B', '9971': 'B'},
'ORG': {'2': 23, '9970': 52, '9971': 52},
'START': {'2': pd.Timestamp('2014-07-31 17:21:59'),
 '9970': pd.Timestamp('2011-12-15 17:59:59'),
 '9971': pd.Timestamp('2011-08-07 04:59:59')}})

monthly = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='1970-01-01', end="2017-04-01 23:59:59", freq="MS"))[0].transform(lambda m : (( mtx.loc[(mtx["EQ"].isin(fsc)) & (mtx["START"] >= pd.to_datetime(m)) & (mtx["START"] <= pd.to_datetime(m) + MonthEnd(1))]).groupby(["ORG","LOC"])["HOURS"].mean()))
monthly = monthly.stack().stack().reset_index()
monthly_tmp = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='1970-01-01', end="2017-04-01 23:59:59", freq="MS"))[0].transform(lambda m : (( mtx.loc[(mtx["EQ"].isin(fsc)) & (mtx["START"] >= pd.to_datetime(m)) & (mtx["START"] <= pd.to_datetime(m) + MonthEnd(1))]).groupby(["ORG","LOC"])["HOURS"].sum()))
monthly = pd.merge(monthly,monthly_tmp.stack().stack().reset_index(),on=["level_0","LOC","ORG"],how="left")
```

gives:

```
pd.DataFrame({'0_x': {0: 10.0, 1: 18.0},
'0_y': {0: 10.0, 1: 18.0},
'LOC': {0: 'B', 1: 'B'},
'ORG': {0: 52, 1: 52},
'level_0': {0: 499, 1: 503}}
```

How can I do all of those in one run?
I tried:

```
f = {'HOURS': 'mean','HOURS': 'sum'}
pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='1970-01-01', end="2017-04-01 23:59:59", freq="MS"))[0].transform(lambda m : (( mtx.loc[(mtx["EQ"].isin(fsc)) & (mtx["START"] >= pd.to_datetime(m)) & (mtx["START"] <= pd.to_datetime(m) + MonthEnd(1))]).groupby(["ORG","LOC"]).agg(f)))
```

But it returns the DataFrame in a different weird way.

Comment: shows us some sample data

Comment: Your example doesn't work. Could you please have a second llok?

Comment: Thanks, I added the two imports, i'm running pandas v. 0.20.3 and it works for me

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do. For example, your result ignores LOC 'A'

Comment: For each month, I want to group data by ORG and LOC and get the mean and sum of the monthly hours. LOC 'A' isn't in the result because it doesn't fall in the specified time range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.agg()` with transpose. It wont give you your exact output but you can manipulate that in pandas:

```
.groupby(["ORG","LOC"])['HOURS'].agg(['mean', 'sum']).T.unstack())).stack().stack().stack().reset_index()
```

so just using your example

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='1970-01-01', end="2017-04-01 23:59:59", freq="MS"))[0].transform(lambda m : ((mtx.loc[(mtx["EQ"].isin(fsc)) & (mtx["START"] >= pd.to_datetime(m)) & (mtx["START"] <= pd.to_datetime(m) + MonthEnd(1))]).groupby(["ORG","LOC"])['HOURS'].agg(['mean', 'sum']).T.unstack())).stack().stack().stack().reset_index()
```

and  you will get

```
   level_0  level_1 LOC  ORG     0
0   499     mean    B    52     10.0
1   499     sum     B    52     10.0
2   503     mean    B    52     18.0
3   503     sum     B    52     18.0
```

Not sure if that output is what you are looking for but you can just do something like:

```
new_df['mean'] = new_df[new_df['level_1'] == 'mean'][0]
new_df['sum'] = new_df[new_df['level_1'] == 'sum'][0]
new_df['sum'] = new_df['sum'].shift(-1)
new_df[~new_df['mean'].isna()].drop(columns=['level_1',0])

    level_0 LOC  ORG    mean    sum
0    499     B   52     10.0    10.0
2    503     B   52     18.0    18.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for. `shift(-1)` didn't work for me, I used `new_df.pivot_table(values=0, index=["level_0","LOC","ORG"], columns='level_1').reset_index()` instead

Comment: @TobSta using `pivot_table` makes the most sense and is far cleaner. Do not know why I did not use it in my answer.